# Any way to use Google Apps Script to update/refresh Linked Slides in a presentation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Is there any way to use Google Apps Script to update/refresh Linked Slides in a presentation?

I'm aware that linked Charts can be updated programatically with .getSheetsCharts() and .refresh().

Comment: Hi Aleister, I'm not sure what you mean? Are you asking if there is a way to refresh slides that are embedded in slides?

Comment: @JasonAllshorn I have a Google Slides document/presentation that contains a dozen or so slides that are linked from other presentations.  In order to update those slides, I have to go to each of them and click the drop-down menu next to the link icon in the upper-right corner of the slide and choose "Update".  This is similar to embedded/linked charts from Sheets.  I can write an Apps Script function that updates linked charts, but this functionality does not appear to exist for updating linked slides.  Essentially, I want is a batchUpdate() that I can addToUi() onOpen().

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for the solution of your question, how about this? By the update at January 4, 2019, a method for achieving this situation was added. The method is `refreshSlide()`.

#### Sample script:

This sample script is from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#refreshslide). But that sample script doesn't work because of 2 errors. So I modified it.

```
var currentPresentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
var sourcePresentation = SlidesApp.openById('sourcePresentationId'); // Please set this.
var sourceSlide = sourcePresentation.getSlides()[0];
var linkedSlide = currentPresentation.appendSlide(sourceSlide, SlidesApp.SlideLinkingMode.LINKED); // Modified

sourceSlide.insertTextBox('hello world'); // Only the source slide has the text box. // Modified

linkedSlide.refreshSlide(); // The linked slide now has the text box.
```

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Append a slide from source Slides to the current Slides.
2. Add a text box to the source Slides.
3. Refresh the current Slides using `refreshSlide()`.

   - By this, the update of source Slides is reflected to the current Slides.

#### Reference:

- [refreshSlide()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#refreshslide)