# Google Apps Script to Refresh Google Slide Presentation containing linked Google Sheet Charts: Fails after 10000 Calls?

Tags: google-apps-script

Our non-profit information display is a simple looping Google Slides presentation, which works well for static content.  Our dynamic content are composed of some current weather textual charts sourced from a Google Sheet (populated using API).  These charts are 'refreshed' using a Google Apps Script every minute.  Why every minute?  Since one of the dynamic charts is the current time -- and this is the only way we have found to maintain a real-time clock in a Google Slide display.

In any case, this works fine -- but after running an entire week, every minute (10000 calls?) the linked charts fail with an 'exclamation mark in a triangle' symbol (and the message 'Image could not be loaded').  Re-embedding the charts does not help -- it is as if the entire Google Slide presentation is now corrupted and unusable for this purpose. We 'fix' this by merely creating a replacement copy of the presentation -- which (after re-activating our triggers to refresh) works just fine. It would be great if we did not need to maintain our presentation this way every week.  Help?  Suggestions?  Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is our Google Slides 'refresh' code:

```
function refreshCharts(){
  var gotSlides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  for (var i = 0; i < gotSlides.length; i++) {
    var slide = gotSlides[i];
    var sheetsCharts = slide.getSheetsCharts();
    for (var k = 0; k < sheetsCharts.length; k++) {
      var shChart = sheetsCharts[k];
      shChart.refresh();
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE 2: I recently moved away from using Google Slides for this purpose (information kiosk) for our non-profit, and we are now using this instead:

1. HTML5 script to display PNG/JPG images as 'slides', with the benefit of being able to force a refresh at the '00' second mark.
2. Use of a Linux cron-based script to call time (from system) and weather/astrotime (from free API) and insert as text on top of a PNG image using the 'ImageMagick' utility.
3. Use Linux simple 'http-server' to display the HTML5 slideshow, rather than Apache, etc. and casting this to out Chromecast monitor(s).
4. Move scheduled audio announcements out out HTML5 script and into simple MP3 files for casting directly to another sound-only Chromecast/speaker.
5. Also simple static slideshow of our static content PNG slides directly on a Chromecast using 'Ambient' mode with our slides stored in a Google Photos album.

To answer the question by Rachael below, here was an example of working Google App Script code to retrieve a screeshot from a website (satellite image) and insert it into a Google Slides presentation (requiring the registration of an API) -- but when I went to re-test it today, it no longer works and presents an error :(

```
function insertGeoSphereScreenshot() {
  var siteUrl = "https://geosphere.ssec.wisc.edu/#coordinate:-1491254,4621696;zoom:5.3;idle_hide:1";
  var pageSpeedApiKey = "(private)";
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" + encodeURIComponent(siteUrl) + "&key=" + pageSpeedApiKey;
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var obj = JSON.parse(res);
  //var imgData = obj.lighthouseResult.audits['final-screenshot'].details.data; // low resolution!
  var imgData = obj.lighthouseResult.audits['full-page-screenshot'].details['screenshot'].data;
  var strImage = imgData.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(strImage), "image/jpeg", "sample.jpeg");
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[3];
  var images = slide.getImages();
  var image1 = images[0]; 
  image1.remove();
  var position = {left:0, top: 0};
  //var size = {width: 1350, height: 940};
  //var size = {width: 675, height: 470};
  //var size = {width: 570, height: 400}; // good fit
  var size = {width: 700, height: 400};
  slide.insertImage(blob, position.left, position.top, size.width, size.height);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252421/any-way-to-use-google-apps-script-to-update-refresh-linked-slides-in-a-presentat

Comment: @Cooper, yes, your link explains how to create/use a 'refresh' script, just like we are using.  The problem is that it appears that *too many calls* to such a script eventually fails to maintain our links -- and we are curious how to avoid that fate.

Comment: First I would check the [Google Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) to see if you are exceeding any of them.  If not then post your code so that we can see if there are any ways of improving on it.

Comment: @TheWizEd, I had never considered the possibility that our trigger calls had exceeded a quota limit, so I appreciate the suggestion.  I don't believe that is the problem in our situation, since the rough guess as to daily time consumed is 70 minutes -- whereas the trigger quota for regular accounts is 90 minutes.  As well, we are not receiving any messages/emails suggesting that a quota has been exceeded. Our trigger code for this task appears to be generic, but I will post it in the next comment.

Comment: Perhaps try [Slides.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) with `refreshSheetsChart`

Comment: Have you tried just putting a Utilities.sleep() in the loop to slow it down a bit.  Often with quotas it's not the actual number but the rate of occurrence that's the problem

Comment: @Cooper, we currently call our refresh trigger once per minute, and it typically seems to take about 3 seconds to execute, so I don't think that it is running too often or too quickly.  As well, to maintain an accurate 'clock' in our Google Slides presentation, we need to run at least once per minute.  We wish there was a built-in function to do this, but this method (of linking a 'date/time' cell in a Google Sheet to a Google Slide) is the only way we have found -- and it works just fine for about one week this way.

Comment: For an example of what our Google Sheet charts linked into our Google Slides presentation looks like:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtLRH.png)

Comment: Yes but you refresh clock rate is much faster in the function loop

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

If you are interested to try batch update I put together a simple example script.

**Code.gs**

```
function updateCharts() {
  try {
    let id = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId();
    let chartIds = [];
    let slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
    slides.forEach( slide =>  { let charts = slide.getSheetsCharts();
                                charts.forEach( chart => chartIds.push(chart.getObjectId()) );
                              }
                  );
    console.log(chartIds);
    let charts = chartIds.map( id => { return { refreshSheetsChart: { objectId: id } } } );
    console.log(charts);
    let requests = { requests: charts };
    Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(requests,id);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
6:54:40 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:54:40 AM  Info    [ 'g139f22bb9da_0_0' ]
6:54:40 AM  Info    [ { refreshSheetsChart: { objectId: 'g139f22bb9da_0_0' } } ]
6:54:42 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Slides.batchUpdate()](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation and code!  I (think) I needed to change the "Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(requests,id);" to use lowercase "slides", otherwise undefined.  However, when it is then run it produces another error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'batchUpdate' of undefined]".

What benefit do you believe this new style of trigger code will have compared to the one we are currently using?

Comment: In the script editor you need to activate the Google Slides API service.  Batch update often overcomes a lot of the quotas that are imposed on scripts because the requests are submitted to a batch queue.

Comment: figured out what you explained.  Typical trigger runs now take roughly half the duration time, which is interesting.  Now we wait to see if our refresh will survive longer or even thrive! :)  Thanks!

Comment: Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: Update -- unfortunately, the new method exhibited the same Google Slide inserted chart problem that the original method used, after a number of days of running just fine.  The good news is that I have found a superior method that (so far) works great for me -- Google Apps scripts to read external data (from API) and insert *directly* into Google Slides presentation -- bypassing the Google Sheets 'middleman' and (failing) links to Google Slides from there.  Furthermore, I have figured out how to display/hide slides and also insert screenshots from other websites into Google Slides :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too. I had a company wide Google Slide deck. The "Primary Deck" was comprised of 3-4 slides owned by each department. The Departmental slides were then linked into the "Primary Deck". This allows each Department to have their own deck and update anytime they wanted. More importantly, it ensured that the HR department didn't mess up the slide formatting from the Accounting Department.

I used a similar auto update script, and it worked great, until the 10,000ish reload and we got the Red Exclamation mark

I ran this up the chain with Google support, and they claimed their was an unlisted limit on versioning and objects in a Google Slide. Each time the slides changed and/or updated, the counter would increase. Ultimately, they had no fix.

In the end my solution was to simply create a Primary Slide template that was linked, but had no Google App Script to update it. Then make a copy and apply the App Script for auto update. When the time came where we hit the limit, I would delete that instance, make a copy of the template, and apply the code.

Not the best automation, but it worked well enough.

TLDR: Google has an unlisted limit on objects and versions for Google Slides that causes an error on images around 10,000 reloads.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this same exact issue, using sheets/slides in almost the same exact way (I also wanted a current time) - and was not able to find much support for it, I even opened up a google issue for it: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/167706666

For anyone else that comes across this post like I did, I also wanted to share my solutions.

First the "no code" way I initally used was to abandon the current time display (since my data technically did not need to be updated every minute), then I linked my charts to a separate presentation that had the "auto update" trigger, then used the "linked slides" feature to copy the slides from my separate presentation into my display presentation, and then I manually update the main presentation - that way if the "auto update" broke things again, it would only break my separate presentation and not my main display board (since I have the URL hard coded into the pi running my board). Not an ideal soultion, but my data is something that usually only changes once a day so updating the linked objects once a day worked well enough.

Then I got brave and started to play with apps scripts and with the help of a lot of googling, here is a script I used to insert the time - it uses the "Title" of a text box to figure out where you want to insert your data then updates it. The other methods I kept finding used "dummy text" and the replace function, which does not really work when you are dynamically changing something over and over (like time).

```
function updateTime() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slidesLength = presentation.getSlides().length;


  //set up update time  
  for (var counter = 0; counter < slidesLength; counter = counter + 1) {
  var dateTitle = "Updated Date"; 
  var date = new Date();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT-5", "M/dd/yy")
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[counter];
  var shapes = slide.getShapes();
  var s = shapes.filter(function(e) {return e.getTitle() == dateTitle}); //find all text boxes with date title
     if (s.length > 0) {
     s[0].getText().setText("Updated as of: " + date); //set current date
  }
}
```

Since all of my data is housed in a spreadsheet, I also expanded this script to pull my data from my spreadsheet to write into my presentation - and same with you, so far it seems to be behaving itself!

Also, I know I am supposed to "avoid asking for clarificaition on other answers", but if you could point me into the direction resources for how you inserted a webpage screenshot into your presentation, that would help me tackle my next adventure!

Either way I hope this helps someone like me who only "kinda" knows coding and scripting :)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay!  I did have some nicely working to insert website screenshot images into a Google Slides presentation, but now it no longer works -- no idea why!  I suspect another change in Google's API.

Comment: Rachael, so my updated post for the inclusion of the code that you requested :)